# Why are api requests not getting throttled when simulated via JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance, jmeter-plugins, performance-testing

I have a get api that gives data pertaining to a store based on the storeid passed in the api endpoint. The implementation is such that if more than 50 hits in a second, the api is throttled and a message ought to be displayed as 'Throttled, wait 7 seconds' wth http code 503

When I simulate with 100 hits or even 200 hits via JMeter the spi gives 200 every tine and there's no throttling but when I simulate the same via shell the api gets throttled properly most 50 responses and the aforementioned throttled message is displayed.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that you really don't send 100 or 200 hits per second with JMeter, the actual throughput is less therefore you are not getting errors.

Double check how many requests per second are **actually** being made using i.e. [Transactions per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) and/or [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) listeners. If you don't see real requests going above 50 - you will need to increase number of threads (virtual users) in [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) accordingly.

Or even better switch to [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) combination. Given you connect them via [Schedule Feedback Function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) JMeter will automatically kick off extra threads to reach/maintain the desired throughput.

Last 2 cents:

- You can install all the aforementioned plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)
- Make sure to [run your test in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and follow other [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as it might be the case JMeter isn't simply capable of sending that many simultaneous requests due to improper configuration/usage

Comment: Dmitri: The number of threads is 200 and ramp up time 1 sec. Why do you then doubt that it isn't really a 200 hits per second simulation?